# How to access user space function argument (struct pointer) in bpf?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I am using libbpf-bootstrap. For me the application "**test.c**" exists and its code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct state_foo {
   int a;
   int b;
}


void foo(struct state_foo *s)
{
    sleep(1);
}

int main() {
    struct state_foo s_org = {0,0};
    struct state_foo *s = &s_org;
    s->a = 10; s->b = 10;
    foo(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print or retrieve the value of "a", a member variable of struct state_foo, when the bpf program attached to function "foo" is triggered. (via bpf_prink).

below is my bpf program (**uprobe.bpf.c**).

```
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>

#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

char LICENSE[] SEC("license") = "Dual BSD/GPL";
    
struct state_foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

SEC("uprobe")
void BPF_KPROBE(uprobe_test, struct state_foo *s) 
{
    int a_user = BPF_PROBE_READ_USER(s, a); //compile ok. but err -22 when run.
}
```

below is program (**uprobe.c**) which is used to attach my bpf program (**uprobe.bpf.c**) to user function "foo".

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: (LGPL-2.1 OR BSD-2-Clause)
/* Copyright (c) 2020 Facebook */
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>
#include "uprobe_test.skel.h"

static int libbpf_print_fn(enum libbpf_print_level level, const char *format, va_list args)
{
    return vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
}


    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        struct uprobe_test_bpf *skel;
        int err, i;
        LIBBPF_OPTS(bpf_uprobe_opts, uprobe_test_opts);
    
        /* Set up libbpf errors and debug info callback */
        libbpf_set_print(libbpf_print_fn);
    
        /* Load and verify BPF application */
        skel = uprobe_test_bpf__open_and_load();
        if (!skel) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open and load BPF skeleton\n");
            return 1;
        }
    
    
        uprobe_test_opts.func_name = "foo";
        uprobe_test_opts.retprobe = false;
        skel->links.uprobe_test = bpf_program__attach_uprobe_opts(
            skel->progs.uprobe_test, -1 , "/home/cih/test.o",
            0, &uprobe_test_opts );
        if (!skel->links.uprobe_test) {
            err = -errno;
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to attach uprobe (uprobe_test): %d\n", err);
            goto cleanup;
        }
    
        printf("Successfully started! Please run `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe` "
               "to see output of the BPF programs.\n");
    
        while (1) {
            printf("running app\n");
            sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
    
    cleanup:
        uprobe_test_bpf__destroy(skel);
        return -err;
    }
```

But, when I try to run, libbpf show errors as follows.

```
libbpf: prog 'uprobe_test': BPF program load failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'uprobe_test': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
Unrecognized arg#0 type PTR
; void BPF_KPROBE(uprobe_test, struct state_foo *s) 
0: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +112)
1: <invalid CO-RE relocation>
failed to resolve CO-RE relocation <byte_off> [11] struct state_foo.b (0:1 @ offset 4)
processed 2 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
libbpf: prog 'uprobe_test': failed to load: -22
libbpf: failed to load object 'uprobe_test_bpf'
libbpf: failed to load BPF skeleton 'uprobe_test_bpf': -22
Failed to open and load BPF skeleton
```

Could you please give me some hints as to why this error occurs?

If the form of the function "foo" is not "`foo(struct state_foo *s)`" but is equal to "`foo(int a)`", it has been confirmed that the bpf program is executed normally and the value of "a" is printed correctly.
However, a problem occurred when the argument was "struct". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

`struct state_foo *s;  s->a = 10;` is invalid as pointer `s` does not yet have a valid value to do `s->a`.

Comment: @Dusol, It does matter.

Comment: Oh, I corrected my original code I posted. Sorry. But error is still exists I mentioned.

Comment: @Dusol Poor stack overflow etiquette to change the question/code once answers arrive.  Better to _append_ if needed.  Else we risk answer in, question change, answer in, question change, ... with the question changes invalidating answers.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks for telling me about that.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Stack Overflow "etiquette" also includes avoiding answering a question containing a **typo**, like access to obviously uninitialized variable. One may point to a typo in the comments below the question post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I saw OP's original code with the uninitialized `s` as a candidate problem, that may explain some issues OP is having and not just a typo.  As answer is wiki, you can vote down, vote up, edit or even delete it.  OP [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77436138/how-to-access-user-space-function-argument-struct-pointer-in-bpf/77436153?noredirect=1#comment136516376_77436153) benefitting from the answer and comments.